# Keep Excel process running with high priority when losing focus in UI

Tags: excel, vba

We have some trouble getting Excel sheet to perform sufficient when the window loses focus. The sheet gathers financial feeds and does some (VBA based) processing before submitting to another feed. The feed needs to be re-calculated every second and must be running while working with other programs (inluding other instances of Excel). Running Excel 2013 on Windows 10.

As long as the Excel sheet has focus, everything works perfectly. But if switching to other programs (including other instances of Excel) the performance drops to an unacceptable level - even though the machine still has plenty of available ressources (CPU, memory). It seems Excel/Windows limits resources to  windows that does not have focus.

Is there any way to tell Excel to use the necessary resources? 
What we tried so far:

1) starting Excel sheet with high priority - bat file with:

```
start "high priority excel" /max /high C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\Excel.exe <name of Excel file>
```

In Task Manager we see that the Excel instance is running with high priority, but still the performance is limited when losing focus.

2) Tweaking registry setting Win32PrioritySeparation to control priority between background/foreground processes:
    HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\PriorityControl\Win32PrioritySeparation

Trying to set this to "8" seemed to have some effect, but not enough - Excel not in focus still not allowed to use resources to maintain performance.

Any help or inputs would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not have this excel running on a dedicated computer or do you only have access to one? If it is that important ...

Comment: Were these answers helpfull in any way? https://superuser.com/questions/6400/how-do-you-keep-microsoft-excel-running-at-full-speed-even-when-it-does-not-have

Comment: The users needs to run this one together with a bunch of other Excel sheets at the same time. Sometimes they interact with the Excel sheet with the feeds and does some manual updates. So unfortunately running this on a separate machine is not acceptable for the users.